# If $u$ is harmonic then $u^2$ is harmonic?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

If $u$ is harmonic then $u^2$ is harmonic?

**My attempt:**
As $u$ is harmonic then $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$ Moreover, $(u^2)_{xx}=2u_x.u_x+u_{xx}.2u$
and $(u^2)_{yy}=2u_y.u_y+u_{yy}.2u$

Then
$$(u^2)_{xx}+(u^2)_{yy}=2(u_x)^2+u_{xx}.2u+2(u_y)^2+2u.u_{yy}=2((u_x)^2+(u_y)^2)\not=0$$

This implies $u^2$ is not harmonic. Is correct this?

Comment: Well, to show that something isn't true you need to provide an explicit counterexample... for example, $u(x) = x$ works...

Comment: This is one of the ways you can show $u$ and $u^2$ are both harmonic if and only if $u$ is constant.

Comment: @Zarrax - the statement above is not true unless $u$ is real as holomorphic functions are harmonic and obviously if $f$ holomorphic, $f^2$ holomorphic. The problem here requires the extra hypothesis $u$ real to conclude

Comment: @Conrad Harmonic functions are generally considered to be real functions.

Comment: @Zarrax - there is a large literature about complex harmonic functions and some famous theorems like Rado-Knesser-Choquet or Lewy's theorem (which extend well-known results about holomorphic functions), so I wouldn't assume that unless specifed, especially when a question is tagged complex analysis and I answered a while ago questions here regarding Rado-Knesser-Choquet for example

Comment: In a complex analysis course, when $u(x,y)$ denotes a harmonic function it is considered to be a real-valued function. Also note that the last line of the OP's argument indicated that $2(u_x)^2 + 2(u_y)^2 $ is nonzero. It's reasonable to infer that the question is in the context of a typical complex analysis class, and not advanced research (I've even seen this exact question before).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our OP Bvss12's argument is essentially correct, save fore one small detail:  the condition

$u_x^2 + u_y^2 \ne 0 \tag 1$

is satisfied if and only if $u$ is *non-constant*; otherwise, if $u$ *is* constant, then

$u_x = u_y = 0, \tag 2$

and (1) cannot bind. The point is that for constant  $u$, $u^2$ is constant as well, and constant functions are harmonic; but for a *non-constant* harmonic function $u$, $u^2$ is not harmonic by virtue of (1).

This may in fact be seen in a co-ordinate free manner by means of the identity

$\nabla \cdot (u\nabla u) = \nabla u \cdot \nabla u + u \nabla^2 u;  \tag 3$

using this, we have

$\nabla^2 u^2 = \nabla \cdot \nabla u^2 = \nabla \cdot (2u\nabla u) = 2 \nabla \cdot (u \nabla u) = 2 \nabla u \cdot \nabla u + 2 u \nabla^2 u; \tag 4$

with $u$ harmonic,

$\nabla^2 u = 0, \tag 5$

(4) yields

$\nabla^2 u^2 = 2 \nabla u \cdot \nabla u \ge 0,  \tag 6$

with equality holding if and only if

$\nabla u = 0, \tag 7$

the condition that $u$ be constant.

In closing it should be observed that the conclusion that $u^2$ harmonic implies $u$ constant requires the underlying assumption that the domain $D$ of $u$ is a *connected* set; otherwise the most we can achieve is that $u$ must be constant on the connected components of $D$, since the constancy of $u$ is derived from path integrals of the form

$u(Q) - u(P) = \displaystyle \int_{\gamma(t)} \nabla u(\gamma(s)) \cdot \dot \gamma(s) \; ds \tag 8$

where $\gamma(t)$ is a differentiable path joining $P$ and $Q$; this integral vanishes when

$\nabla(\gamma(t)) = 0; \tag 9$

but since $\gamma(t)$ must lie in a single component of $D$, we can only infer that $u$ is constant on such a set; $u$ may take different values on different components of $D$.

Finally, we observe that this argument extends into a any number of dimensions; there is nothing intrinsically two dimensional about what has been herein presented.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Your calculation shows that $\Delta u^2=2u\Delta u+2|\nabla u|^2$ for any function $u$ whatsoever. So $u$ and $u^2$ both being harmonic implies that $2|\nabla u|^2=0$, i.e. $u$ is constant.